# grep log lines of a specific id request

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

So, I have the following log sample:

```
2015-03-30 10:19:44,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCD] A log message 1
2015-03-30 10:19:45,250 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCD] A log message 2
2015-03-30 10:19:45,700 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCD] log message of exception occurred in 
abc.cdef.class.sdk.SampleException: Message exception..
<stacktrace lines goes here>
2015-03-30 10:19:46,100 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCD] A log message 3
2015-03-30 10:19:46,120 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCD] A log message 4
2015-03-30 10:19:46,120 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d800e80-5276-4006-a44d-dd4cea7bcbe1 Info:P13 Code:AB4D] A log message 6
```

Each request that comes in the server as a unique IDA.
I want to grep all lines of log that have a certain IDA and put in another logfile with all the occurrences found. 
I’m using grep because it also append the file and line number ( grep –n ) where those patterns were found (the serach goes on 2 ou 3 files). 
But still, I also want that the stacktrace exceptions to be included, which is not happening because those lines don’t have the IDA that I am searching.

Furthermore that stacktrace exception may also happen as part of the last entry for a specific IDA, like this:

```
2015-03-30 10:19:44,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCD] A log message 1
2015-03-30 10:19:45,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:BECD] A log message 2
2015-03-30 10:19:44,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:DFCD] A log message 3
2015-03-30 10:19:45,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:BBCD] A log message 4
2015-03-30 10:19:45,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4 Info:P23 Code:ABCC] log message of exception occurred in 
abc.cdef.class.sdk.SampleException: Message exception..
<stacktrace lines goes here>
2015-03-30 10:19:45,200 DEBUG [Default : 1] [Application:ABC BIW: IDA:ed8ede83-1116-4697-a69d-ee6cd575cbe7 Info:P23 Code:ABDD] A log message 5
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

P.S.1- I've been searching around, but I've mostle found searches between tags, which in my case is not good enough.

P.S.2-My solution os currently just a one liner grep, but i am open to other solutions, such as perl, awk, sed, python or any other "bash command way to go".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '$id = "6d87de8e-1276-4496-b49d-dd4cd375cbe4";
          print if $match = (/IDA:$id/ .. /IDA:(?!$id)/)
                and $match !~ /E0$/
         ' *.log
```

Explanation:

- `/regex1/ .. /regex2/` returns true for lines between the matches.
- `IDA:(?!$id)` meand `IDA:` *not followed* by $id.
- the last line in a range is denoted by the `E0` suffix which the condition checks, so the last line (the one with a different IDA) is not printed.

To include file names and line numbers, use

```
print "$ARGV:$.:$_"
```

and add the following before the closing quote:

```
; $. = 0 if eof
```

Comment: This is printing duplicates, i.e. lines matched preceeded by filename where it was found and another entry without the filename preceeded.

Comment: @jik: You don't show any such lines in the samples.

Comment: I mean you solution is giving me duplicates. Is not my sample that has those.

Comment: @jik: When I run it on your samples, I don't get any duplicates. Maybe replace the `*.log` with the actual mask that doesn't include output of your previous grep command?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry, my bad. But still, how do I get here the file name where it was found and the line number?

Comment: @jik: check the update.

Comment: I surrender :) Works perfectly. Answer accepted.I must definitely go into perl more deeply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This prints the respective data (each preceded with the line number) to files named as the IDA:

```
awk 'match($0,/IDA:[^ ]+/) { print NR, $0 > substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4) }' logfile
```

Comment: Exceptions are not considered here. Still is a nice awk work.

Answer (score 1):

`Sed` solution:

```
sed -n ':2;/IDA:6d87de8/{p;/exception/{:1;n;/IDA:/!{p;b1};b2}}'
```

The script suppres output (`-n` option), until meet appropriate IDA (`/IDA:6d87de8/`) which will be printed (`p`). Then pattern(line) will be checked for "exeption" presence and, if so, starts to operate with next line (`n`). If the next line do not consist `IDA:` the line will be printed and script goes to next line(loop started at `:1` point). If the line cosist `IDA:` script starts from the begining(loop at `:2` point)

If you'd like to enumerate lines - output lines by `nl` or `grep -n ".*"` and pipe it to `sed` script.